# Traverse a user's file system in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh

I'm currently building a rails web app that scans users' file systems but need the gaps in my knowledge base cleared first. I've been working it out in my head for the past few months but am a bit hazy at what would need to occur under the hood between the point where users hit the 'scan my system now!!' button and my app actually scanning their file system and reporting the results.

EDIT: After reconsidering the security implications, I have chosen to make this a desktop application which then allows users to upload their results to a rails app.

Comment: This question needs to be closed because it's no longer valid, but it should remain on Stack Overflow as a reminder that it's not possible to do.

Comment: I don't know why the downvote, you'll need to ask all the other users who viewed it.

Comment: Downvote is probably someone who considers this very obvious (its easy to forget these things), or by someone who thinks that the question is too localized.

Answer (score 3):

Web apps cannot read the local filesystem unless a user drags the files into the app (`<input type="file">`). You can't just peruse the local filesystem -- that would be a massive security risk. Not even web plugins allow this (unless you hack Java or Flash -- shouldn't be too hard :)). You would need to the user to install software like an SSH server (too complicated) or something you make (a lot of work).

Anyway, no web app should ever need to read whole parts of the filesystem.

This just can't be a webapp. It needs to be a desktop app. Period. Web access to filesystem is like giving hackers a sheet with everything they need to be a pain, or worse. Just no.

Comment: @Anconia - I think the closest model and best way to look at this problem is to see how on-line virus scanners are implemented. If what you want is a file scanner then follow that model (in most cases a downloadable Java app or desktop exe).

Comment: @Casper: Exactly. And, frankly, I trust a desktop app I download directly much more than some embedded Java (which no one should have enabled anyway).

Comment: I think he understands the risk,  and needs to do it anyway, and wants to use ssh.  I think a more moderate response would be 'start this project as a simple ruby program, using net-ssh,  flush out the mechanics of your file scanning protocol.  Once that simple ruby program, and all the attendant ssh setup is working,  THEN you could wire it up to a website if you need to.

Comment: But you can only SSH in if they're running an SSH server -- which most people aren't.

Comment: As long as those clients are cooperative in regards to the ssh setup, and the added security risk of opening up their systems to access via ssh, then the approach seems fine to me.

Comment: @Linuxios This seems like some kind of intranet type application,  not a public web application,  AM I correct in this assumption?  If this is a Public site, the Linuxios is correct,  it's unworkable ,  an SSH server on a windows box is very RARE.

Comment: @anconia: try SFTP, or try https.

Comment: @radbrad yes. SSH also offers much more access then is nessisary for this.application, opening security hole.